# Responsive height of slider div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with swiper slider and I need your help.

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/2Xt7H/4

I want the `comm_image_div` div which is the slider div to take the height of the image and not to be fixed (200px) as it is in my example.

I prefer to do this with css, but if this isn't possible then the alternative is javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display: inline-block;`  and delete the `height: 200px;`   in `#comm_image_div`

Using `display: inline-block;` will change the div's height and width(if they are not specified) according to its content.

UPDATE: 
I used `height: 100%;` in `#comm_image_div` and `img.comm_image_big`
http://jsfiddle.net/2Xt7H/7/

Comment: Try adding `display: inline-block;` to the wrapper div and container div, too

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2Xt7H/3/  I have added a border with color red to your `comm_image_div` and it looks like the div's height is equel to the images height. Or I didn't understand what you want.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2Xt7H/4/ I updated my example to help you. I want to remove the white part under the image.

Comment: Can you use a margin-top value like:  `margin-top: -10px;` in your sub-div  like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2Xt7H/5/

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I do not want to set pixels to remove the white space because in that way my site is not responsive.

Comment: The problem now is that the image is not responsive. I want the image ratio to remain the same as the viewport change.